# How to merge changes from electron-react-boilerplate to my repository?

Tags: git, github, merge, electron-react-boilerplate

I have a private repository in GitHub. I cloned electron-react-boilerplate and then, I changed the origin to my repository. I have made some significant changes (Changed the renderer and some eslint and TS config as it was too strict for me) and pushed it to my Private Repo.

2 days after, ERB released v4.3.0. Now, how do I merge the changes to my repo? Should I start from scratch again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set multiple remotes. Here is the reference on how to do that. [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

After setting a remote say named `alt`. You can do

`git pull alt master`

Comment: It does really work. I have been pushing 20 commits flawlessly. I also found a amazon post about this - [Click here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-mirror-repo-pushes.html)